# Surface height distribution for Jupiter's moon Io?

Tags: io, topographic-map

The [moon Io](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Io_(moon)#Mountains) has around 100 mountains:

> These structures average $6 {\rm\, km}$ in height and reach a maximum of ${\rm 17.5 \pm 1.5\, km}$

I am now looking for the overall histogram, i.e. **elevation distribution of Io's surface** and/or a **[hypsometric curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypsometry#Hypsometric_curve) for Io**.

#### References

- JPL: [Topography of Io](https://www.jpl.nasa.gov/images/topography-of-io-color)

Comment: https://planetarygeomorphology.wordpress.com/2017/07/28/global-stereo-topography-of-jupiters-moon-io/ and references therein might contain what you look for

Comment: Since you mention the heights of peaks in your question, did you really mean to ask for the distribution of *peak heights* instead of a distribution of all heights? "These structures average 6 km in height..." can't come from a histogram of all heights, it's first necessary to filter the topography and find the local maxima and turn that into a list before analyzing further.

Comment: @uhoh I would indeed like to have the overall height distribution,  but the peak height distribution would also be nice. I was wrong to assume that I could deduce the latter from the overall distribution. What I also would love to have is a statistics about the heights of the volcanos. Many sources I saw explicitly exclude the volcanos, I guess since they are so variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This blog](https://planetarygeomorphology.wordpress.com/2017/07/28/global-stereo-topography-of-jupiters-moon-io/) by Butcher and Conwey on Geomorphology (or should we say io-morphology?) was a good starter. It seems usual to deal with the distribution of mountains and volcanos on Io. There are height maps (DEM) which give the distribution colour-coded. The closes to a hysometric curve found for Io is in this paper by [White et al (2014)](https://agupubs.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/epdf/10.1002/2013JE004591) which gives a hypsometric curve where they exclude the volcanos in figure 9. [image]

Noteworthy might also be [this poster](https://pubs.usgs.gov/sim/3168/sim3168_sheet.pdf) by Wiliams et al with geological map but also a height distribution given single measurement "points" (where the points are areas of various size).